# redis zrange vs zrangebyscore(-inf +inf)

Tags: redis

Which method is better in next case:

I need to get a few elements which are ordered by score, I can use both methods:

```
 1. zrange myZset 1 5 WITHSCORES
 2. zrangebyscore myZset -inf +inf WITHSCORES 4 1
```

In redis documentation both methods has Time complexity: O(log(N)+M)

So, is there any diference in time execution within my case

Comment: Can you please tell me that from 1st command how can you get sorted values? or you're setting ordered values?

Comment: @Mayank Jain redis stores elements ordered by score in sorted set, and I meaned getting elements ordered by their score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time with 10k itterations on 60k elements in zset:

*zrange myZset 1 5 WITHSCORES*: **0.70670008659363**

*zrangebyscore myZset -inf +inf WITHSCORES 4 1*: **1.0469110012054**